# Running Harbor with Istio and Cert Manager

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio, cert-manager, harbor

I have been trying to pull images from Harbor for a few days now but no luck yet. I'm using harbor bitnami chart, Version v2.8.2, istio 1.16.1, cert manager v1.12.0 and argocd 2.7.6.

Pushing images to harbor works with DroneCI an the ui works well too but pulling is not working with this error, whether with argocd or docker. docker can not login with the same error:
login attempt to https://harbor.example.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
Please let me know if you know how to config this to work.

harbor values:

```
adminPassword: ""
externalURL: https://harbor.example.com
commonName: harbor.example.com
```

istio gw:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: gateway
namespace: istio-system
spec:
selector:
istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
servers:

port:
number: 80
name: http
protocol: HTTP2
hosts:
"*"
tls:
httpsRedirect: true
port:
number: 443
name: https
protocol: HTTPS
hosts:
"*"
tls:
mode: SIMPLE
credentialName: wildcardtls
```

istio vs : (which I got from here and have tried all the solutions: #77, goharbor/harbor#3114)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
name: harbor
namespace: istio-system
spec:
gateways:
- gateway
hosts:
- harbor.example.com
http:
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/c/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-core.harbor.svc.cluster.local
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/api/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-core.harbor.svc.cluster.local
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/v2/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-registry.harbor.svc.cluster.local
port:
number: 5000
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/v1/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-registry.harbor.svc.cluster.local
port:
number: 5000
fault:
abort:
httpStatus: 404
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/service/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-core.harbor.svc.cluster.local
- match:
- uri:
prefix: '/chartrepo/'
route:
- destination:
host: harbor-core.harbor.svc.cluster.local
- route:
- destination:
host: harbor-portal.harbor.svc.cluster.local
```